# Script for Google Sheets to Move Row to New Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am having some issues with a shop schedule I am trying to set up. I would like to have en entire row be moved the corresponding new tab when certain data is entered into column "J". I have included an editable link for a sample sheet I created that also helps explain what I am trying to do.

If possible, it would also be helpful to be able to make the backgrounds change to the colors on the sample sheet as well.

Thank you!

Editable Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D0iptPchrrLuq75ysvXwisBa_Xr0fuNabAdTb3sm-yA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you want them to be copied or completely moved to the other sheet? WHat have you tried already?

Comment: This is not difficult. Made a copy of your sheet and working on a script that would do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a crude code that will work, however if you change the value to the same that it is on (so if it's in complete, and you edit it to change to 20) it will just delete the row. It would be easy to fix, but I just don't have the time right now :)

EDIT: just remembered to note, that it will use the last row, so for moving stuff back to appointments you should move the legend to the top of the sheet :) Or you should just get rid of the move back to appointments bit altogether. You can also play around with how the variables are worked with, I just don't like grabbing the sheets again so I send a lot of them to the move function.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  //get active spreadsheet
  var srcSheet = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet();  //get active sheet

  var editCol = e.range.getColumn(); //check the edited column
  if (editCol!==10) {return}  //if the edited column is not J then we don't need to do anything else
  var srcLastCol = srcSheet.getLastColumn(); //check how large is our data range
  var srcRow = srcSheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1, 1, srcLastCol); //get the source row range
  var srcVals = srcRow.getValues(); //get the values from the source fow
  var destSheet, destRow, destRange; //destination variables
  Logger.log(e.value)

  if (e.value>=1 && e.value<=14) {  //for 1-14 we use we assign 1 sheet, the same function for everything
    moveRow('In Shop', srcRow, srcVals, srcLastCol, spreadSheet);
  }  
  else {  //for everything else we use a switch
    switch(e.value) {
      case '15':
        moveRow('Arrive / In Lot', srcRow, srcVals, srcLastCol, spreadSheet);
        break;
      case '17':
        moveRow('Waiting on Parts, Truck, Etc.', srcRow, srcVals, srcLastCol, spreadSheet);     
        break;
      case '20':
        moveRow('Completed', srcRow, srcVals, srcLastCol, spreadSheet);
        break;
      default :
        moveRow('Appointments', srcRow, srcVals, srcLastCol, spreadSheet);
      }
  }  
}

function moveRow(destName, srcRow, srcVals, srcLastCol, spreadSheet) {
  var destRow
  var destSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(destName)
  destRow = destSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  destSheet.getRange(destRow, 1, 1, srcLastCol).setValues(srcVals)
  srcRow.clear()
}
```

**EDIT2**
Answering comments

```
function moveRow(destName, srcRow, srcVals, srcLastCol) {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var destRow
  var destSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(destName)
    destRow = destSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    destSheet.getRange(destRow, 1, 1, srcLastCol).setValues(srcVals)
    srcRow.clear()
}
```

However, that would be bad practice for any larger script that has a long runtime. You would then waste time accessing the SpreadsheetApp every time.

As for the colours, it's a fairly simple adjustment in the moveRow():

```
function moveRow(destName, srcRow, srcVals, srcLastCol, spreadSheet) {
  var destRow
  var destSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(destName);
  destRow = destSheet.getLastRow() + 1;

  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destRow, 1, 1, srcLastCol);
  destRange.setValues(srcVals);
  destRange.setBackground(destSheet.getTabColor())
  srcRow.clear()
}
```

As for sorting, this is where you need to have `destSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(destName);` before calling the moveRow(). So bellow, let's assume that you retrieve the destSheet somewhere before the `if` or in the `if` itself. This sample will sort it by column A in ascending order (so adjust the 1 to what you need, let's say you want J, then it would be 10)

```
  if (e.value>=1 && e.value<=14) {
    moveRow('In Shop', srcRow, srcVals, srcLastCol, spreadSheet);
    destSheet.sort(1)acceding order
  }
```

Comment: Vytautas, that works great! Thank you! One more question, how would I go about having the backgrounds change to the corresponding colors, depending on which tab it is on? Also, have the ones for "In Shop" be automatically sorted numerically? 

In addition, what do you mean by grabbing sheets again & which variables would I try changing? Sorry for all the questions. I am still barely understanding how scripts work :(

Comment: Not enough chars and the formatting will be horrible to explain everything here. I would urge you to start using the [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) as it is very easy to follow (just click on the return type and follow each function you need). As for grabbing sheets, each `spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` will take time, so instead of having the function perform this action again, I simply send the object reference from the main function to the moveRow(), so I don't have to do it again and waste execution time

Comment: Okay, thank you. The only issue I am seeing now, is when I put something into "In Shop" once I add another one, it will delete and replace the one that was already there. Even if the numbers are different. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I think this is happening because I am not putting the "sort" script in the right area? Also, is there a way to not have anything happen if any other numbers than those mentioned are put in. I am just wondering because it a number is entered by accident that is not in the code, that row of information seems to be erased, or moved somewhere? So basically, if anything besides 15, 17, 20 is entered, the information stays at "Appointment". Although thought this is already set up with using
'default :
        moveRow('Appointments', srcRow, srcVals, srcLastCol, spreadSheet);
      }'

Comment: _Sidenote: don't leave 2 functions with the same name in the code._ Yes, you can limit it. Like I said, this is a basic code that I threw together in a couple of minutes. You just need to specific with the else. You may want to just use switch in that situation. Read how to use multiple criteria [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) The deleting happens due to my error in the code. I will edit it. Essentially in the moveRow function change `if (destRow === 0) {destRow++}` to just `destRow++` or change `destRow = destSheet.getLastRow()+1`